# Draggable div inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this html code i want to make the color divs draggable and then fit them in the table cell aside

the green div should fit 2 cell spaces, the light blue 3 cell spaces, the yellow 4 cell spaces and the dark blue 5 cell spaces.

i have the draggable code but how can i make it so it would make them divs fit and stay in the table cell

[image]

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var turno = 0;
var bomba = 1;
var bombaClick = 0;
var arregloLetras = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];

$('#bomb-attack').on('click', function() {
  bombaClick = 1;
});

$('#oponentBoard td#options').on('click', function() {
  var celda = $(this).attr('class');
  var datos = celda.split('-');
  $(this).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
  if (bombaClick == 1) {
    if (bomba == 1) {
      selectAround(datos[0], datos[1]);
      bomba = 0;
      $('#bomb-attack').attr("disabled", true);
    }
  }
});

function selectAround(letra, numero) {
  var indexLetra = arregloLetras.indexOf(letra);
  var indexNumero = parseInt(numero);
  var indexLetraAtras, indexLetraAdelante, indexNumeroAdelante, indexNumeroAtras = -1;

  if (indexLetra > 0)
    indexLetraAtras = indexLetra - 1;
  if (indexLetra < 9)
    indexLetraAdelante = indexLetra + 1;

  if (indexNumero > 1)
    indexNumeroAtras = indexNumero - 1;
  if (indexNumero < 10)
    indexNumeroAdelante = indexNumero + 1;

  if (indexLetraAtras != -1) {
    $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAtras] + '-' + indexNumero).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    if (indexNumeroAdelante != -1)
      $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAtras] + '-' + indexNumeroAdelante).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    if (indexNumeroAtras != -1)
      $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAtras] + '-' + indexNumeroAtras).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
  }
  if (indexLetraAdelante != -1) {
    $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAdelante] + '-' + indexNumero).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    if (indexNumeroAdelante != -1)
      $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAdelante] + '-' + indexNumeroAdelante).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    if (indexNumeroAtras != -1)
      $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAdelante] + '-' + indexNumeroAtras).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
  }
  if (indexNumeroAdelante != -1)
    $('#oponentBoard td.' + letra + '-' + indexNumeroAdelante).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
  if (indexNumeroAtras != -1)
    $('#oponentBoard td.' + letra + '-' + indexNumeroAtras).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
}

$(function() {
  //$( ".draggable" ).resizable();
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: "clone",
    snap: "#drop_here td",
    opacity: 0.7
  });

  $("#drop_here td").droppable({
    // accept only from left div,
    // this is necessary  to prevent clones duplicating inside droppable
    accept: '#left .draggable',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      // 4 append clone to droppable
      $(this).append(
        // 1 clone draggable helper
        $(ui.helper).clone()
        // 2 make the clone draggable
        .draggable({
          containment: "parent"
        })
        // 3 make the clone resizable
        .resizable());
    }
  });
}); < /script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/css/style-override.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/css/jquery-ui.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well well-md">
        <h3>Boats</h3>
        <div class="draggable boat boat-small ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
        <div class="draggable boat boat-medium ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
        <div class="draggable boat boat-medium ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
        <div class="draggable boat boat-large ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
        <div class="draggable boat boat-xlarge ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="well well-md"> -->
      <div class="well well-md">
        <h3>Attack</h3>
        <button id="bomb-attack" class="btn btn-danger">Bomb!!</button>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="well well-md"> -->
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="col-md-3"> -->

    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-0 well well-md">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="yourBoard" class="boards">
          <h3>My Board</h3>
          <table id="drop_here" class="table table-bordered board-bg">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">1</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">2</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">3</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">4</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">5</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">6</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">7</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">8</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">9</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">10</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">A</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">B</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">C</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">D</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">E</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">F</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">G</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">H</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">I</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">J</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- <div id='yourBoard' class='boards'> -->
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="col-md-6"> -->

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="oponentBoard" class="boards">
          <h3>Oponent</h3>
          <table class="table table-bordered board-bg">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%"></td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">1</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">2</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">3</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">4</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">5</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">6</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">7</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">8</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">9</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">10</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">A</td>
                <td id="options" class="A-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">B</td>
                <td id="options" class="B-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">C</td>
                <td id="options" class="C-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">D</td>
                <td id="options" class="D-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">E</td>
                <td id="options" class="E-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">F</td>
                <td id="options" class="F-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">G</td>
                <td id="options" class="G-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">H</td>
                <td id="options" class="H-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">I</td>
                <td id="options" class="I-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">J</td>
                <td id="options" class="J-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-10"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- <div id='oponentBoard' class='boards'> -->
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="col-md-6"> -->
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 well well-md"> -->
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="row"> -->
</div>
```

This is the expected result
[image]

Comment: 1. Can you post the result of this code? (not the `php`) so we could edit your code and answer you. 2. I don't understand what the problem is? can you provide more details about where are you "stuck"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, It's not the final result but it's a direction. Now, the drag and drop are working, but you take care of the rectangle's position in the `td` and more.

It took a few changes in your code and it is difficult to specify them. Just track the changes in the code.

```js
var turno = 0;
var bomba = 1;
var bombaClick = 0;
var arregloLetras = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];

$('#bomb-attack').on('click', function() {
  bombaClick = 1;
});

$('#oponentBoard td#options').on('click', function() {
  var celda = $(this).attr('class');
  var datos = celda.split('-');
  $(this).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
  if (bombaClick == 1) {
    if (bomba == 1) {
      selectAround(datos[0], datos[1]);
      bomba = 0;
      $('#bomb-attack').attr("disabled", true);
    }
  }
});

function selectAround(letra, numero) {
  var indexLetra = arregloLetras.indexOf(letra);
  var indexNumero = parseInt(numero);
  var indexLetraAtras, indexLetraAdelante, indexNumeroAdelante, indexNumeroAtras = -1;

  if (indexLetra > 0)
    indexLetraAtras = indexLetra - 1;
  if (indexLetra < 9)
    indexLetraAdelante = indexLetra + 1;

  if (indexNumero > 1)
    indexNumeroAtras = indexNumero - 1;
  if (indexNumero < 10)
    indexNumeroAdelante = indexNumero + 1;

  if (indexLetraAtras != -1) {
    $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAtras] + '-' + indexNumero).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    if (indexNumeroAdelante != -1)
      $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAtras] + '-' + indexNumeroAdelante).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    if (indexNumeroAtras != -1)
      $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAtras] + '-' + indexNumeroAtras).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
  }
  if (indexLetraAdelante != -1) {
    $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAdelante] + '-' + indexNumero).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    if (indexNumeroAdelante != -1)
      $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAdelante] + '-' + indexNumeroAdelante).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    if (indexNumeroAtras != -1)
      $('#oponentBoard td.' + arregloLetras[indexLetraAdelante] + '-' + indexNumeroAtras).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
  }
  if (indexNumeroAdelante != -1)
    $('#oponentBoard td.' + letra + '-' + indexNumeroAdelante).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
  if (indexNumeroAtras != -1)
    $('#oponentBoard td.' + letra + '-' + indexNumeroAtras).css('background-color', '#FF0000');
}

$(function() {
  //$( ".draggable" ).resizable();
  $(".ships .draggable").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: "clone",
    snap: "#drop_here td",
    opacity: 0.7
  });

  $("#drop_here td").droppable({
    // accept only from left div,
    // this is necessary  to prevent clones duplicating inside droppable
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      // 4 append clone to droppable
      $(this).append(
        // 1 clone draggable helper
        $(ui.helper).clone().removeAttr('style')
        // 2 make the clone draggable
        .draggable({
          containment: "parent"
        })
        // 3 make the clone resizable
        .resizable());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/css/style-override.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/css/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.jobfeedpro.com/battleship/includes/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="ships well well-md">
        <h3>Boats</h3>
        <div class="draggable boat boat-small ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
        <div class="draggable boat boat-medium ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
        <div class="draggable boat boat-medium ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
        <div class="draggable boat boat-large ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
        <div class="draggable boat boat-xlarge ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="well well-md"> -->
      <div class="well well-md">
        <h3>Attack</h3>
        <button id="bomb-attack" class="btn btn-danger">Bomb!!</button>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="well well-md"> -->
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="col-md-3"> -->

    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-0 well well-md">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="yourBoard" class="boards">
          <h3>My Board</h3>
          <table id="drop_here" class="table table-bordered board-bg">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">1</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">2</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">3</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">4</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">5</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">6</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">7</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">8</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">9</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">10</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">A</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">B</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">C</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">D</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">E</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">F</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">G</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">H</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">I</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable">J</td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
                <td width="1%" class="ui-droppable"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- <div id='yourBoard' class='boards'> -->
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="col-md-6"> -->

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="oponentBoard" class="boards">
          <h3>Oponent</h3>
          <table class="table table-bordered board-bg">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%"></td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">1</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">2</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">3</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">4</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">5</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">6</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">7</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">8</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">9</td>
                <td class="ui-droppable" width="1%">10</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">A</td>
                <td id="options" class="A-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="A-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">B</td>
                <td id="options" class="B-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="B-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">C</td>
                <td id="options" class="C-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="C-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">D</td>
                <td id="options" class="D-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="D-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">E</td>
                <td id="options" class="E-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="E-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">F</td>
                <td id="options" class="F-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="F-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">G</td>
                <td id="options" class="G-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="G-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">H</td>
                <td id="options" class="H-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="H-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">I</td>
                <td id="options" class="I-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="I-10"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="1%">J</td>
                <td id="options" class="J-1"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-2"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-3"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-4"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-5"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-6"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-7"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-8"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-9"></td>
                <td id="options" class="J-10"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- <div id='oponentBoard' class='boards'> -->
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="col-md-6"> -->
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 well well-md"> -->
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="row"> -->
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/liwoyi/edit?html,js,output